# AS3 converting an Event to a MouseEvent

Tags: actionscript-3, events, mouseevent

Is it possible to convert an Event to a MouseEvent in AS3 (Visa versa)? I have a function that calls another function but one is an eventlistener (enterframe) and it calls another function that accepts a mouseEvent.

Appreciate any help. Couldn't find anything on Google...

Regards
Luben

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do something like this

```
 function yourMouseFunction (evt:MouseEvent = null) {

       // do you stuff
 }
```

In this way, you can call your function passing or not the parameter.

Comment: You're welcome :) Mark the answer as the good one for future people